# Jupyter notebook dead kernal

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I was doing a project in Colab. But when I copy the same code in my jupyter notebook in my MacBook , I get a dead kernal message when I run the following imports.

```
import os
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
import scipy
import cv2
%matplotlib inline

np.random.seed(2)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import itertools

from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau, ModelCheckpoint
from keras.models import model_from_json

import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Any Ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: please add the error you're receiving

Comment: First I get a pop-up saying Kernel Restarting- The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically. Then on the top right corner, it says DEAD KERNEL in a red box.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `conda` has not installed properly in your system. Try again by uninstalling the anaconda and install it back from scratch.

Please check this [link](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/) to install Anaconda.

After installing Anaconda in your system, Create virtual environment to install Tensorflow in it as below:

To install the current release of CPU-only TensorFlow,

```
conda create -n tf tensorflow
conda activate tf
```

Or, to install the current release of GPU TensorFlow

```
conda create -n tf-gpu tensorflow-gpu
conda activate tf-gpu
```

You can also create virtual environment in Anaconda Environment section. Open the Jupyter notebook by selecting the same virtual environment.

run below code:

```
conda install pip
pip install tensorflow
```

After doing all these setups, your code may run fine as I have already executed above code in Jupyter and its not showing any error.